# Control the movement space for an object?

Tags: unity

[image]
I want my object not cross the limit of "AiX\AiZ" values. When object cross this limit it faces like walls that block him but not stop him from movement.

```
public GameObject Player, middleObject;
public float high, upForce, speed;
public float PlayerDistance, AiX, AiZ, PlayerNum;
public Vector3 PlayerPlace,PrediactPlace;

void Update()
{

    Quaternion currentRotation = transform.rotation;
    Quaternion wantedRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, wantedRotation, Time.deltaTime * 10);

    AiX = gameObject.transform.position.x - middleObject.transform.position.x;
    AiZ = gameObject.transform.position.z - middleObject.transform.position.z;

    if (PlayerNum == 0) // control it from inspector 
    {
        Player = null;
    }
    else
    {

        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GPlayer");
        PlayerDistance = Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, Player.transform.position);
        PrediactPlace = Player.GetComponent<PlayerCtrl>().Point.position;

        if (AiX <= 2 && AiZ >= -2 && AiZ <= 7 && AiZ >= -7)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, PrediactPlace, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to clamp your destination position using Min/Max functions, then MoveTowards that location.

```
public PlayerCtrl player;
public Transform middleObject;
public float speed;
public float playerNum;

void Update()
{

    Quaternion currentRotation = transform.rotation;
    Quaternion wantedRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(currentRotation, wantedRotation, Time.deltaTime * 180f);

    if (playerNum == 0) // control it from inspector 
    {
        player = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Vector3 predictedPlace = player.Point.position;

        Vector3 offset = predictedPlace - middleObject.position;

        Vector3 halfExtents = new Vector3(2, 0, 7);
        Vector3 outer = middleObject.position + halfExtents;
        Vector3 inner = middleObject.position - halfExtents;

        Vector3 moveTarget = Vector3.Max(inner, Vector3.Min(predictedPlace, outer));

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveTarget, Time.deltaTime * speed);    
    }

}
```